# How to get rid of waves in pagetheme, instead stick to one color?

Tags: reactjs, backstage

Looking for some help to change the page theme to one color instead of waves.

```
home: genPageTheme({colors: ['#FFFFFF', '#FFF'], shape: shapes.wave}),
```

Any one ran into this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Hej!  Answered this question in Discord as well. You can customise your theme following this example (https://backstage.io/docs/getting-started/app-custom-theme#example-of-a-custom-theme). In your theme you want to have smth. like the following:

```
const myTheme = createTheme({
  ...lightTheme,
  defaultPageTheme: 'home',
  pageTheme: {
    home: genPageTheme({ colors: ['#8c4351', '#343b58'], shape: 'none' }),
  },
});
```

This way you would only have the linear gradient between the 2 colours. You can also just have one single colour in the colors array.

Comment: Thanks Philipp for the insights. Is there a way to remove the gradient which is what I am trying to eliminate. 
My requirement is to have single color header border without any wave or gradient designs.

Comment: with e.g. `genPageTheme({ colors: ['#8c4351'], shape: 'none' }),` you would have a single colour in the `linear-gradient` (so basically avoiding the gradient) or you statically override the CSS for BackstageHeaders like the following: https://github.com/backstage/demo/blob/e7d0d604fe5571e730fa6f34cdb3073d8f226542/packages/app/src/theme/aperture.ts#L85-L89